# Can intellij shows Maven dependencies in tree structure rather than flat?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am importing a Maven project into Intellij and I found that IntelliJ imports all the dependencies in flat, although my project is only depending on only 1 library.

Any clue on how to change this?

Comment: mvn dependency:tree will show the tree of dependencies.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/05/maven-dependencies-diagram/